# File goes missing for a short period of time after saving it using VIM

Tags: linux, vim, ecryptfs

I am having a strange problem that seams to be caused by VIM, the Linux VFS cache, ecryptfs and/or something file system related:

1. I open a file in VIM, modify it and save it.
2. I try to access the file.

### Expected behaviour

The file should be accessible as soon as `:w` reports the file as written.

### Actual behaviour

The file does not exist.

If I wait a bit (usually less then a second) the file turns up.

This is especially cumbersome when working with Python code and left over `pyc` files. I often ended up starting the old code as the new `py` file was not ready, yet. I recently added `export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` to my `.bashrc` so I get a meaningful error message rather than executing the old code. It is still very awkward as any auto reloader code (e.g. from Django) fails to reload every 5-10 times because the file I changed goes missing for a short period of time. With the `pyc` files in place the auto reloader sometimes ended up loading the old `pyc` file and after that never found out that the `py` file has been modified and triggered another reload.

### System details and configuration

My machine has plenty of RAM (32 GiB), an SSD and is basicly idle. Therefore I do not think that slow I/O is causing this. The file is very small (<1 KiB) and it also happens for empty files. I am using a crypted `$HOME` using ecryptfs so this might be part of the problem. I was unable to reproduce this on my `/tmp` mount which uses a `tmpfs` file system.

### VIM settings

The reason why the file is moved away and replaced by a new file is caused by my VIM settings:

```
set backup
set backupskip=
set backupdir=$HOME/.vimbackup
set writebackup
```

I would expect the `new` file to be accessible right after VIM reports that the file has been written. I checked the VIM documentation for any hints of a delayed write, but did not find anything. I was unable to reproduce this using the shell commands `mv`, `cp` and `rm` so I think VIM is doing something different.

---

What else could be causing this? How can I solve this.

Comment: I'd like to add that I'm experiencing the same problem on OS X (10.11) on both Vim (7.4) and NeoVim (0.1.4) , due to `backupdir`, thus this probably discards issues with the filesystem. It's likely a bug/miss-feature on Vim still present on NeoVim.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug but it isn't related to the one that Aaron linked to. I'm unable to reproduce it at the moment, so can you please file a new bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+filebug

You can copy and paste from the description above, but I also need to know more about the Linux distribution and kernel version that you're using. Thanks!

Comment: You are probably right. Bug filed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/1123267

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a bug / by-design defect in ecryptfs. See this [launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/311314).

In a nutshell, ecryptfs simply doesn't write the file to disk immediately. My guess this is because of the encryption overhead (the filesystem probably encrypts the data in a background thread and writes it only after that has completed).

The bug is from 2009 and the priority is "Wishlist" (which is below "Low"). I am a bit worried how "[enterprise](http://ecryptfs.org/)" and such a behavior mixes; as you found out, a lot of code expects files to be usable right away after saving them.

Try to use [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) instead.

Comment: Even if the file is not immediately written to the disk (I have not set the VIM `fsync` option) it should be instantly available via the Linux VFS. The linked bug is an interesting read but is probably not related to my issue. btw. I'm probably going to switch to dm-crypt/LUKS in foreseeable future. TrueCrypt is a no-go for me because of its rather weird license.

Answer (score 1):

I think the behaviour you see is just because the Vim backup process is slow. On my plain Ext4 system, this problem manifests as a "file is empty" error from the compiler.

To check the timings, I used this Bash sequence:

```
strace -tt -o /dev/stdout gvim --nofork main.cxx | grep 'main.cxx\|close'
```

With backups turned on, I see a 200 ms gap between the file disappearing and it finally getting saved:

```
09:06:49.587341 rename("main.cxx", "main.cxx~") = 0
09:06:49.668654 open("main.cxx", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644) = 12
09:06:49.755454 close(12)               = 0
```

When I use `set nowritebackup` in my `.vimrc`, the file does not get renamed; there's only an open and a close:

```
09:19:45.731416 open("main.cxx", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644) = 12
09:19:45.815763 close(12)               = 0
```

Is this a good explanation for the problem you're experiencing?

---

P.S. I couldn't find any other mention of this problem on the [Vim issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/list?can=1&q=backup&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&cells=tiles), or on the Vim [developer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/vim_dev/backup)/[user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/vim_use/backup) mailing lists, so I can't say whether the Vim team would consider changing the backup system call sequence.

Comment: Since writing this question I have switched to dm-crypt with LUKS and this problem is no longer as prevalent as it used to be. After digging into the VIM manual I found the `backupcopy` option which explains the behavior you found using strace. When switching to `backupcopy=yes` that rename no longer happens. Sadly the write is not atomic either. For me the best sequence for writing a file would be: 1.) write new file with a temporary name 2.) create hardlink of the original file if possible (copy it if this is not possible) 3.) rename new file to the target filename.

Comment: Still I don't get why VIM reports the file as written when in fact it is not? I even experienced this issue when working with two terminals: one VIM the other where I start the a compiler or another application by hand. VIM reports the file as being written while the other app returns a "no such file or directory" error. I guess I will have to open a bug in VIM for this. I'm just curious as I seam to be the only one affected by this so far.